# When you get response from an addProximityAlert how do you know for which setup you got it?

Tags: android, proximity

I add to system a lot of POIs via [addProximityAlert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993830/whats-wrong-with-this-addproximity-code).
When I have got the alert, I don't know for which setting has occurred.

The only Extra that is passes is the 'entering' flag as it is described in the documentation.

How can I know that?

**After the answers here is the working code:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlacesProximityHandlerService.class);
intent.setAction("PlacesProximityHandlerService");
intent.putExtra("lat", objPlace.getLat());
intent.putExtra("lon", objPlace.getLon());
intent.putExtra("error_m", objPlace.getError()+ALERT_RANGE_IN_METERS);
PendingIntent sender=PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
LocationUtils.addProximity(this, objPlace.getLat(), objPlace.getLon(),objPlace.getError()+ALERT_RANGE_IN_METERS, -1, sender);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom action string on your `Intent`s that you wrap in the `PendingIntent`s, so you can tell the different ones apart, for example.